# GNU `ls` has `--quoting-style` option, what's the equivalent in BSD `ls`

Tags: ls, bsd

I will use ls output for pipe input, so I need to escape the file name. when I use GNU `ls`, It works well. what's the equivalent in BSD `ls`? I hoping the output is like this.

```
$ gls --quoting-style escape t*1
text\ 1  text1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are/were you trying to use `ls` in a pipeline?  You should probably be using `find` (maybe with `-print0` and `xargs -0`, or `-exec`).

I suppose you could use `ls -1f` and then run the output through `vis` (or some similar filter) with some appropriate options to add the necessary quoting or escaping of your choice, but without knowing what you are feeding filenames into, and what (if any) other options you would want to use with `ls`, it's impossible to give much better guidance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [freebsd man page on `ls`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ls) there is no such option, however, you can try `-m` which will give you a comma separated streamed output:

```
-m       Stream output format; list files across the page, separated by
         commas.
```

I tried it on osx and it gave me:

```
$ ls -m
Hello World, Hello World.txt, foo.txt
```

That is a lot easier to parse from a script.

Comment: The manual lies by omission -- the output from `-m` is _also_ line separated and it is not so easy to parse, though I guess it depends on exactly what scripting language one uses.  I think you will find the normal newline-separated stream of names from `find`, or `ls -1`, is far easier to parse with the likes of `sh` and `awk` and similar.   Whenever you start having to parse multiple lines each with multiple items you end up with two separators that cause you problems.  With just newlines as the one and only separator it is far less likely that you'll have to worry about quoting.